# Android Push Notifications on Android Device that can not install Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I have a Android Device that does not have Google Play Services on it and can not because it is not a certified device.

I am looking for a way to send Push Notifications to this device to wake it up and process an incoming message.

We have the ability to customize the Android BSP (ASOP) if there is any possible way to create our own custom Push Notification server to accomplish this?

Comment: You may consider using a paid product such as Pushy (https://pushy.me) to send push notifications without relying on GCM / Google Play Services. Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Just the other day I had the same question. My scenario involved real time notifications though. Everything is updated in real time . and the idea of using web sockets came to me. And luckily I knew socket.io , luckily android had a native build with gradle. Consider researching into this concept.

Right off the bat. Features like back off time checks, back pressure and timeouts.